# How to locate and write to textfield and click submit with HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, html, http, htmlunit

I am completely new to HtmlUnit and I do not really know how to read and understand the page source of a website. Nonetheless, I have written code (learned from this [tutorial](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html)) to try and access the following website

Then I am stuck, as I am not familiar with javascript. This is what I want to achieve:

- **I would like to type `328` in the textfield on the left menu on
  that website**
- and **click submit button**

*So that I can be brought to the next page.*

**UPDATE:** I managed to resolve page access problem by adding a line to my code. But I am still having trouble to locate the input text field, type in some input and click the button, so that i can be landed to the next page.

```
public void testing() throws Exception {
           /* turn off annoying htmlunit warnings */
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.aastocks.com/en/stock/DetailQuote.aspx?&symbol=1");
        final HtmlDivision div = page.getHtmlElementById("LeftMenu_Button");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The website has a CSS with URL `//:`, which wasn't correctly handled by HtmlUnit, and it is now fixed in SVN.

Please get the [latest build](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts), with which the below code works:

```
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {

        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.aastocks.com/en/stock/DetailQuote.aspx?&symbol1");
        HtmlInput input = page.getHtmlElementById("PY_txt");
        input.type("328");

        final HtmlPage page2 = page.getHtmlElementById("imgHKStockSubmit").click();
        System.out.println(page2.getUrl());
        System.out.println(page2.asText());
    }
```